# Mod Rewrite Wilcard Subdomain - Internal Pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

- i am able to get subdomain variables (product name and language) with php via $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]

http://product.en.example.com

I do not know how to make to work in browser these urls for internal pages:

- product.en.example.com/images
- product.en.example.com/images/john
- product.en.example.com/hobbies
- product.en.example.com/hobbies/smith

images, hobbies = pageType

john, smith = peopleName

I think i should get the pageType via php query strings (GET) and serve the corresponding layout.

In .htaccess i have:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.(.+?)\.example\.com/$ 
RewriteRule (.+).(.+)\.example\.com\/(.*) /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. First of all you can parse the request uri in php using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which contains the requested URI.

An alternative is to use your `.htaccess` file. In this case you would not even have to parse the server name in php:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.?([^\.]+?)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?/?(.*?)/?$ /index.php?product=%1&language=%2&pageType=$1&peopleName=$2 [L]
```

Note that I added the rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` instead of your check against `index.php` because this way you can serve assets like your css files without having them redirected to index.php.

Beware that `HTTP_HOST` has no trailing slash.

**EDIT**

As requirested in the comments:

In order to add another *optional* parameter you can use `([^/]*)?/?`. Therefore the `RewriteRule` could look like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?(.*?)/?$ /index.php?product=%1&language=%2&pageType=$1&peopleName=$2&peopleAge=$3 [L]
```

Comment: It seems to work as desired. I forgot that i also have some urls to categories without first parameter (product). I tried to make optional the point . before language \.? or (\.)? but this url gives 404.thanks
en.example.com/cat/catName

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your new requirements.

Comment: Works fine. I try to add another optional parameter at the end, but does not appear in the query string. Maybe i will have urls with few more parameters. I tried this  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?/?(.*?)/(.*?)?/?$ /index.php?product=%1&language=%2&pageType=$1&peopleName=$2&peopleAge=$3 [L]

Comment: I edited my answer once more to reflect your new requirements.